# goja: how to set a func with a func argument that has variadic parameters?

Tags: javascript, go, debugging

Ultimately, I want to create a function that performs a similar function to `setTimeout`

I'm dealing with some difficulty with variadic parameters.

I set `myFunc` here:

```golang
    err = vm.Set("myFunc", func(f func(a int, b int, extras ...int)) {
        f(1, 2, 3, 4)
    })
// error check
```

executing this JavaScript:

```js
    myFunc((a, b, c, d) => {
        log("DEBUG", a + b);
        log("DEBUG", c + d);
    });
```

gives the output

```
1
2
3,4
```

I'm expecting the output

```
1
2
3
4
```

`c` get's assigned `extras` instead of it being unpacked into `c` and `d`

I just got goja @latest. go.mod contains

```golang
    github.com/dop251/goja v0.0.0-20230812105242-81d76064690d
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the best, but one possibility is like this, where optFrom is an integer field.
Then you can use this function IndexAt("alpha fallon","f") or IndexAt("alpha fallon", "f", 4)

Another option: opt ...any, then you have to take care of the types yourself.

```
func IndexAt(pStr, pSubStr string, optFrom ...int) int { //Index from position
    pos := 0
    if len(optFrom) > 0 {
        pos = optFrom[0]
    }
  ....
}
```